# Cannot install react-app "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked,"

Tags: reactjs

Getting the error while init new react app:

```
$ npm init react-app .

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Juvy Ann\Desktop\Dev__\react-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Juvy Ann\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\81\2e
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, mkdir 'C:\Users\Juvy Ann\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\81\2e'        

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Juvy Ann\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-13T09_19_58_324Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting react-app/ from C:\Users\Juvy Ann\Desktop\Dev__
(node:5516) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'C:\Users\Juvy Ann\Desktop\Dev__\react-app'
    at Object.rmdirSync (fs.js:872:3)
    at rmdirSync (C:\Users\Juvy Ann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\remove\rimraf.js:276:13)
    at Object.rimrafSync [as removeSync] (C:\Users\Juvy Ann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\remove\rimraf.js:252:7)
    at C:\Users\Juvy Ann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:562:14
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:5516) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5516) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a windows user, try deleting all files in this folder:

> C:\Users{{your-username}}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

Then...

> npm cache verify

If that doesn't work, try updating to the lastest (understand the risks)

> npm i npm@latest -g

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue, then I installed the latest version of npm using :
npm i npm@latest -g
and reinstall the react-app. It solved the problem